# Is it possible to have a repeating object in Tiled/Sprite Kit?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, tiled

I'm currently building a game using Xcode, sprite kit and now tiled. The game is simple, a person jumping from 1 block to another, but if they hit the side it will be game over. Now is their anyway through tiled to create a block for the person to jump on. And through out the game to keep repeating and coming on for the person to jump on, I would like the object to have different heights and widths? Please Help?!

Answer (score 0):

What you can go for is creating a reuse mechanism that will reuse nodes instead of creating and destroying them. A mechanism well-known from `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`.

You would implement a method:

```
- (SKNode *)dequeueReusableNode;
```

that gets reused `SKNode` from some storage, say, `NSMutableArray` (grabs first object from array, then deletes it from array and returns it). If array is empty, method returns `nil`.

Then you check if you got a node from the `dequeueReusableNode` method, if it's `nil`, you create a new instance of a node. If it's not `nil`, you configure it with your data. 
This goes for every visible node that should be reused.

Nodes that went completely off-screen are sent to `reuseQueue` – all their property values return to default state, and then node gets added to the end of the `NSMutableArray` that is the `reuseQueue`.

Comment: i'm a beginner at coding so could you give me more of a step by step?